# Rails - console message about associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Everytime I do something in my terminal of my rails 4 app, I now get a message that has this warning:

```
gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1694: warning: already initialized constant User::HABTM_Roles
/Users/ffd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1694: warning: previous definition of HABTM_Roles was here
```

Does anyone know what it means?

In my role.rb, I have:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify



end
```

In my user.rb, I have:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => :users_roles
```

Comment: paste your user.rb & give more clarification about the error

Comment: You might have defined twice a `has_and_belongs_to_many` for the `User::HABTM_Roles` association (or `Roles` association in your user model).

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ - what does that mean? how do i provide  a full path?

Comment: Hi - i don't know what that is.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem and found a simple solution.

I was using in my code previously :

```
module MyModule
  RESET = 'reset'
end
```

I just change this to

```
module MyModule
   RESET ||= 'reset'
end
```

And I got the solution.

So see if you do same in you code somewhere.

This took care of the warning and is a lot simpler than checking if each constant is defined. Let me know if you find a better solution.